# How to export javafx project to mac compatible file

Tags: macos, javafx, build, export

I am trying to export a javafx project from eclipse (4.6.3) to a program that will run on macOS (can also be simple java file that can be opened with jarlauncher).

I have no previous experience in doing this - anyone already familiar with the process or have a link of how to achieve that?

Comment: Easiest is to export your Eclipse project to a runnable jar file. There are more advanced authoring methods but a runnable jar will probably do.

Comment: Did you read https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1